# Vue - Get Current Index / Array Count Based On Parent V-For Array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two nested `v-for` elements that look like:

```
<div class="category" v-for="(category, categoryIndex) in categories">
    <div class="product" v-for"(product, productIndex) in cateogry)">
        {{product.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to show only the first five products, regardless of the number of categories and the number of products in each category.

How would I get the cumulative index count (in relation to the total number of products that's been displayed from the **categoryIndex** parent array) inside of the second `v-for` element?

Comment: Do you mean five products from each category or five products from all categories? Could you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: I would loop through the products and categories in your JS and build a new array to loop through in the template. In your category and product loop you could increment a separate count for each product, and if the count is less than 5, add the product to your new array. That way your logic is all in the JS and you keep the template simple.

Comment: Maybe a computed property that `slice()` your products into an array with 5 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, it will be something like this

```
<div class="category" v-for="(category, categoryIndex) in categories">
    {{ category.name }}
    <div class="product" v-for="(product, productIndex) in category.products.slice(0, nbProductToShow)">
        {{(categoryIndex*nbProductToShow)+(productIndex+1)}}
        {{product.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
    data : {
        nbProductToShow : 5,
        categories : [{
                id : 3445,
                name : 'shoes',
                products : [
                    { id: 23234, name : 'Pink unicorn shoes'}, 
                    // ...
                ]
            },{
                id : 3447,
                name : 'hat',
                products : [
                    { id: 232, name : 'Pink long hat with unicorn'}, 
                    // ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: You can replace `category.products.slice(0, nbProductToShow)` by `splicedProducts` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the product is within the first five products rendering by passing its id to a function and showing the product according to its returned value. Here is an example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="category" v-for="(category, categoryIndex) in categories" :key="categoryIndex">
      <div class="product" v-for="(product, productIndex) in category.products" :key="productIndex">
        <span v-if="incrementCount(product.id)">{{product.name}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          products: [
            { id: 1, name: "1" },
            { id: 2, name: "2" },
            { id: 3, name: "3" },
          ]
        },
        {
          products: [
            { id: 4, name: "4" },
            { id: 5, name: "5" },
            { id: 6, name: "6" },
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    incrementCount: function(id) {
      let count = 0;
      for(let i = 0; i < this.categories.length; i++)
        for(let j = 0; j < this.categories[i].products.length; j++)
          if(count++ < 5 && this.categories[i].products[j].id===id)
            return true;
      return false;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Correspondingly, the output would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```